# Unity3D C#/Variable assigned but never used(?)

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, warnings

I have a little problem, I have my variables written and I can see them declared and used, but the unity console says its value is never used... The variable is `distanceY`

> "Assets/Scripts/CameraWindowMove.cs(17,22): warning CS0414: The private field `CameraWindowMove.distanceY' is assigned but its value is never used"

I don't know what's the problem, can some one help me?

Here's the sample of the code:

```
float distanceX, distanceY;

void Awake ()
{
    playerBoxCollider = GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    windowBoxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    player = GameObject.Find ("Player");

}

void Start ()
{
    x = transform.position.x;
    y = transform.position.y;
    lookAhead = 0;
    distanceX = ((windowBoxCollider.bounds.size.x / 2) - (playerBoxCollider.bounds.size.x / 2));
    distanceY = ((windowBoxCollider.bounds.size.y / 2) - (playerBoxCollider.bounds.size.y / 2));
```

Comment: From your code we can see that `distanceY` is really just assigned and no more used. Do you have code where `distanceY` is in the "right" part of expression?

Comment: and it's not a `unity` tag, it's `unity3d`

Comment: Thank you, you are right, the variable hasn't more use after that, I didn't see it at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a build warning, it will not affect the functionality of your program. This is a valuable warning though, it is letting you know that you created a variable, assigned a value to it, but then never used it at a later point in your program (as far as static analysis can see).

In C# you can disable them via a pragma at the top of your script file

Some common are:

```
#pragma warning disable 0168  // variable declared but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0219  // variable assigned but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0414  // private field assigned but not used.
```

I would not suggest using these disables though as these warnings are useful. This is just for development.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to disable warnings

Answer (score 0):

This warning tell you, that you only setted value to distanceY, but not used it value anywhere.